# Custom menu for a one-page-scroll-theme

Tags: wordpress, menu, scroll

I need change de native behavior of the menu. Instead menu point to URL page (www.domain.com/page-name), i need point to a anchor (#page-slug, for example). Using Menus -> Custom Links i get it, but i need do that using just code.

Besides pointing to an anchor, I need it to be the slug-page.

I need this to create a one-page-scroll-theme. Using this logic, my client would only need to create the pages and choose the order, without touching the Menu panel.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Without you showing code, we can't be much help, however, here is a plugin from wordpress that might do what you want, or help you with the custom coding. [Infinite-Scroll](http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/)

Comment: Lawlanders, i still have no code. I want create a custom menu (with code) which href be a anchor - and the anchor be slug page.